# Invocation was not performed on the mock, what could be wrong here?

Tags: c#, interface, tdd, moq

this error is trown by the following TEST. If i test the DataLayer, the database gets updated and everything works. however the mock keeps sending out this error. i have a similar test that does work with almost the exact code (on the InsertRPAData). the only diffrence i can see is that the XMLDataEntity is a diffrent entity in the test compared to the Verify but both of them use the barcode = 1 though.

this test needs to be worked on and the XMLDataEntity is just there to allow me to verefy the Test. also ignore the return for now.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    _mockRepository = new Mock<IRPADataLayer>();

    UnityUtil.UnityContainer = new UnityContainer();

    UnityUtil.UnityContainer.RegisterInstance(typeof(IRPADataLayer), _mockRepository.Object);
}


[TestMethod]
public void TestDoSuppressions()
{
    //Arange
    var suppressiontest = new Suppression();

    //Import the XML File
    XElement newElement = XElement.Parse(get090XML());
    XDocument testdoc = new XDocument();
    testdoc.Add(newElement);
    String string2Stream = String.Concat("1");
    Stream reader = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(string2Stream));
    RPADataEntity rpa = new RPADataEntity();
    XMLDataEntity test = new XMLDataEntity();
    test.barcode = 1;
    rpa.RPAID = 1;
    rpa.XMLData = testdoc;
    //Act
    Int32 success = suppressiontest.DoSuppressions(reader, rpa);

    //Assert
    _mockRepository.Verify(x => x.UploadPreprocData(rpa, test));
}
```

The method being called is this one.

```
   public Int32 DoSuppressions(Stream reader, RPADataEntity rpa)
   {
       XMLDataEntity test = new XMLDataEntity();
       test.barcode = 1;

       _IRPADataLayer.UploadPreprocData(rpa, test);

       return 1;
   }
```

and the interface is this

```
public interface IRPADataLayer
{
    void InsertPreProcData(PreProcDataEntity PreProcDataEntity);
    void InsertRpaData(RPADataEntity RPADataEntity);

    RPATypeEntity GetRPAType(String type);

    void UploadPreprocData(RPADataEntity rpa, XMLDataEntity xml);
}
```

Comment: What is the question and the problem? I just see code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your verify is expecting a certain instance of `XMLDataEntity`, (the one your instantiating in your test).

However the method that is being tested creates it's own `XMLDataEntity` and calls UploadPreprocData.

So the verification fails because the method hasn't been called with the expected instance of `XMLDataEntity`.

Most mocking frameworks provide a way to to specify that the expected parameter can be of any instance, so that might be what your wanting here.

Hope that helps.

**Edit:** 
In Moq, verifying and excepting any parameter of a given type is done by using:

```
It.IsAny<T>()
```

Where T is the type of the expected instance.

In your case this can be done like so:

```
_mockRepository.Verify(x => x.UploadPreprocData(rpa, It.IsAny<XMLDataEntity>()));
```

Comment: would you happen to know if moq has such a way?

Comment: Thank you, the code works like i wanted it after adding a loop to the update and adding Times.Exactly(count). Still new to moq but this will help me for future cases as well.